# How do I split this string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a task to split the string. First, there are a few operations to perform

```
let currSynonyms = "['rear neck and choke', 'multiple fractures, multiple hairline injuries', 'leukemia']"
currSynonyms = currSynonyms.replace('[', '');
currSynonyms = currSynonyms.replace(']', '');
console.log(currSynonyms);
Output is this string:
'rear neck and choke', 'multiple fractures, multiple hairline injuries', 'leukemia'
```

Now I have to split this so that the 2nd element is not separated with the comma present there.
So, my output should be an array like this:

```
['rear neck and choke', 'multiple fractures, multiple hairline injuries', 'leukemia']
```

If I do currSynonyms.split(',') I get:

```
[
  "'rear neck and choke'",
  " 'multiple fractures",
  " multiple hairline injuries'",
  " 'leukemia'"
]
```

If you do currSynonyms.length you'll get 4 but this is not what I want.
I know I have to somehow use Regular expressions nut I can't figure out how?

Comment: How certain are you about the input string format? Are you in control of it? Slightly silly answer: Remove the first and last two characters, then split by `', '`. Is the problem more complex?

Comment: I'm certain enough. Not in so much control I have to operate with this input itself

Comment: @TheMaster Yeah, this is what I'm also looking for. A regular expression can solve this but I don't know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse would create a problem if the string is like this:

```
let arr = "['abc','xyz','shell's, disease']";
```

Here, the 3rd element has a single quote in it which gives an error when you try to parse it.
So, I came up with a better solution:

```
let arr = "['abc','xyz','shell's, disease']";
arr = arr.replace('[', '')
arr = arr.replace(']', '')
arr = arr.split(/',/);
console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr);

Output:
3
[ "'abc", "'xyz", "'shell's, disease'" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `'` with `"` and [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it:

```js
let arr = "['abc','xyz','shell's, disease']";
const out = JSON.parse(arr.replace(/'(?=,|])|(?<=,|\[)'/g,'"'))
console.info(out)
```

- updated regular expression to catch `'` inside strings

Answer (score 1):

```
let currSynonyms = "['rear neck and choke', 'multiple fractures, multiple hairline injuries', 'leukemia']"

const splittedAsArray = JSON.parse(currSynonyms.replace(/'/g,"\""))
const result = splittedAsArray.join(",").split(",").map(r=>r.trim())
            


console.log(result);
```

This should result in

```
[ 'rear neck and choke',
  'multiple fractures',
  'multiple hairline injuries',
  'leukemia' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since from the given example one also might need to take single quote characters used as apostrophs into account, I suggest a regex based approach like the following one ...

1. remove leading opening bracket and single quote.
2. remove trailing single quote and closing bracket.
3. split at following sequence ...

   - single quote, optional white space sequence (OWSS), comma, OWSS, single quote.

... example ...

```js
const sample = "['rear neck and choke', 'multiple fractures, multiple hairline injuries', 'leukemia','shell's disease']";

/**
 *  1. remove leading opening bracket and single quote.
 *  2. remove trailing single quote and closing bracket.
 *  3. split at following sequence ...
 *     - single quote, optional white space sequence (OWSS),
 *       comma, OWSS, single quote.
 */
console.log(`"${ sample }"`);

console.log(sample
  .replace(/^\['/, '')
  .replace(/'\]$/, '')
  .split(/'\s*,\s*'/g)
);
```